# I deleted my OSX partition, and have no patitions formatted to bootcamp, so I can only access BIOS

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, partition, windows

I recently created a windows 7 partition on my mid-2009 mac-book pro. It then corrupted, so I was forced to delete the partition and attempt to reinstall windows 7, but in the process  I also deleted my OS X partition. Now after spending hours and countless DVD+Rs on creating OS X and Linux boot discs (all of which fail to open anything but BIOS), I am still left with a shell of a computer with no OS.
How can I reinstall OS X/Ubuntu.

Comment: I assume you have another computer or how else are you creating DVD+R's? If so, what kind/model?

Comment: I'm more concerned at what you are considering "BIOS" on a Mac.... Can you provide a picture - take with a phone if necessary, post to imgur/flikr etc & tell us the link - someone with the necessary reputation can inline it into your question

Answer (score 1):

Start Recovery Mode (CMD+R) at boot.

Even if your OS X partition is gone, you should have options to recover/reinstall OS X.

Have a look at: [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely certain, but I doubt that machine can use Internet Recovery, it's too early.
See the list at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313 for those that can be firmware upgraded to use it.

Worst case scenario, if you can't find the disks the machine came with might be to get hold of a retail version of [Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) & once that's successfully installed, you can then upgrade to any previously purchased OS, or jump right to El Capitan, from the App Store.